# How to convert enum to localized enum structure in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, enums

I have a question here to ask. I have an enum which at runtime shows in the UI. It has three values.

```
enum ExpiryOptions
{
   Never,
   After,
   On
}
```

Now from the userControl when it loads its shows Never, After, on.

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="accessCombo" Margin="5" Height="25" Width="80"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=expiryEnum}, 
        Converter={StaticResource enumtoLocalizeConverter}}"/>
```

In English its fine but the problem is, if the software is used as a localized settings the same strings appear. And not any localized strings.

In the converter I have a written a code like this

```
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                    object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            ExpiryOption[] myEnum = value; // This myEnum is having all the enum options.

        // Now what shall I write here
        //if I write a code like this
        if(myEnum[0] == Properties.Resources.Never)
            return Properties.Resources.Never;
        else if(myEnum[1] == Properties.Resources.After)
            return Properties.Resources.After;
        else if(myEnum[2] == Properties.Resources.On)
            return Properties.Resources.On;


        }
```

then the enum in the UI fills with N E V E R (vertically) In English Language settings. Obviously the first string matches and fills with Never other two options are missing. Any suggestions and help is extremely needed.

Comment: I stuff the enum in a dictionary. Key is enum and value is string I want to display.

Answer (score 1):

You are always *returning first enum value from converter* i.e. string value `Never` which is char array hence you are seeing one item as single char in your comboBox.

Instead you should return string list:

```
List<string> descriptions = new List<string>();
foreach(ExpiryOption option in myEnum)
{
   if(option == Properties.Resources.Never)
       descriptions.Add(Properties.Resources.Never);
   else if(option == Properties.Resources.After)
       descriptions.Add(Properties.Resources.After);
   else if(option == Properties.Resources.On)
       descriptions.Add(Properties.Resources.On);
}
return descriptions;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value passed into the ValueConverter to use it as follows.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(ExpiryOptions), typeof(string))]
public class MyEnumConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ExpiryOptions option= 
            (ExpiryOptions)Enum.Parse(typeof(ExpiryOptions),value.ToString());

        // Now that you have the value of the option you can use the culture info 
        // to change the value as you wish and return the changed value.
        return option.ToString();           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have defined resources strings for `Never, After, On` as strings in class `Properties` as `ExpiryOptionsNever, ExpiryOptionsAfter, ExpiryOptionsOn` respectively(of course with strings you need) I would write this converter:

```
public class EnumConverter: IValueConverter{
    public Dictionary<ExpiryOptions, string> localizedValues = new Dictionary<ExpiryOptions, string>();

    public EnumConverter(){
        foreach(ExpiryOptionsvalue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ExpiryOptions)))
        {
             var localizedResources = typeof(Resources).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static).Where(p=>p.Name.StartsWith("ExpiryOptions"));
             string localizedString = localizedResources.Single(p=>p.Name="ExpiryOptions"+value).GetValue(null, null) as string;
             localizedValues.Add(value, localizedString);
        }
    }
    public void Convert(...){
        return localizedValues[(ExpiryOptions)value];
    }
}
```

This is essentially what user Blam suggested in the comments